# Two conditions in Python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4, 5]
```

Is there any way of iterating through both lists in one for loop?
It would go all the way through `b` (should work if they are different lengths).

Something like this:

```
for first in a, second in b:
    print first
    print second
```

Expected output:

```
1
3
2
4
5
```

Comment: Do union on both set..loop through it.

Comment: Those are sets, not lists.

Comment: @rajpy I won't know which value belongs to which list.  Unless I do something like `dict[$value] = $owner`

Comment: What is the expected output ??

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yeah sorry, I just changed the syntax to lists.  But it would be the same intention if with sets.

Comment: @AvinashBabu added expected output

Comment: Sets are not ordered, so pairwise iteration would be nearly meaningless.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: The answer suggested in the *Duplicate* note above does not yield the desired output as depicted in the question.

Comment: `for i, j in map(None, a, b):
print i
print j`

Comment: @rajpy +1 as it works perfectly in my situation as well. I noticed that if I dont include None in map then I get error. Why is None required?